# What's the best way to manage updating third-party components in subversion projects?

Tags: svn

I frequently have svn-based projects that include third-party components such as the TinyMCE (in-browser WYSIWYG) editor. This includes dozens of folders with possibly hundreds of files.

Ideally, when I want to update TinyMCE to the newest release, I'd like to be able to copy the top-level TinyMCE folder into my working copy, commit the changes and away I go.

Obviously, this won't work because by copying over the top I'd be wiping out all the existing `.svn` folders nested through the working copy.

Updating all the files by hand would take hours.

Is there a good way to manage this with svn?

Alternatively, are there any tools (on linux or OS X) that would help me perform the 'manual' copy more easily?

Comment: I would have thought that it **would** be the case that .svn folders would remain if you copy a new version of a third party library.  The copy should just replace existing files and add new files, and not delete anything.

Comment: What sort of copy would merge the two structures?

Comment: Under Windows a (sometimes ctrl-) drag and drop will do this, but you have to reassure it that you do in fact want to overwrite existing files.  Extra files will be added silently, pre-existing (.svn) folders and files will remain, but sadly old files that are missed out from the update won't get deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't understand "Obviously, this won't work because by copying over the top I'd be wiping out all the existing .svn folders nested through the working copy.". Which OS are you using?

I use a Linux Web Server for my SVN Server and a Windows machine for work. There's not such thing as "wipping out" .svn folders: you just copy the files to the the checked out directory, and since they are changed, I just commit them using TortoiseSVN.

This is not the "best way" of keeping your structure. But it works.

Disk space is usually not a concern, so you can usually create a repository of third party applications, so you don't depend on internet access to just build/deploy your application.

```
svnrepositories
  myprojects
    myprojet
  third-party
    tinymce
      1.3
```

And them, use the [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) property, like pointed out by **BrianLy**.

You can just point out to the external resource on the internet. But remember that the disadvantage is that the resource can be offline and you need internet access.

Comment: I'm using OS X. When you copy one folder on top of another, a direct replacement occurs. There's no merging. Do other systems merge? That sounds useful but also pretty dangerous!

Comment: You set me on the path of researching copying methods. It looks like the standard unix `cp -R` command will perform a merge-like copy, which would be good enough for what I want, using the workflow you've outlined. Thanks.

Comment: Since I've never used an OS X, I didn't know about this "direct replacement" behavior. I'm glad you could work it out a way to do what you needed even in this scenario. :)

Comment: There are better solutions, but using the "file copy" method you have asked about, I believe svn export is what you'd want to use to avoid having the .svn-related files from your source project overwrite those in your target folder.

Answer (score 2):

"the best way to manage updating third-party components in subversion"?

[Vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html). As a bonus, you can modify the code of the third-party component, and the modifications will survive updates thanks to merging.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at the [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) property.

Comment: Does that not require the third-party component to also be a svn versioned resource? In this case it's just a folder of stuff downloaded from the web.

Answer (score 1):

use svn:externals including the revision lock parameter -r{REV.NR.}, which ensures that you dont in an untimely fashion get updates from the third-party suppliers svn-repository.

Then you can in your own time, upgrade to the latest version of the thirdparty component, simply by setting the -r{REV.NR.} parameter to the latest revision of the external repository.

Answer (score 0):

Including library version to the path works for me. This way to update the version you simply remove the old one, add the new one and point references to the new path.

```
$ svn del vendor/tinymce-3.4.2
$ svn add vendor/tinymce-3.4.3
$ # edit references to point to vendor/tinymce-3.4.3
```

But if you want to do changes to the library I would opt for vendor branches commented above.